# What qualifies as a "separation axiom?"

Tags: general-topology, soft-question, separation-axioms, metrizability

Wikipedia states the hierarchy of separation axioms as:

$$
\underset{\text{(Kolmogorov)}}{T_0} \impliedby
\underset{\text{(Fréchet)}}{T_1} \impliedby
\underset{\text{(Hausdorff)}}{T_2} \impliedby
\underset{\text{(Urysohn)}}{T_{2½}} \impliedby
\underset{\text{(Regular)}}{T_3} \impliedby
\underset{\text{(Tychonoff)}}{T_{3½}} \impliedby
\underset{\text{(Normal)}}{T_4} \impliedby
\underset{\text{(Completely normal)}}{T_5} \impliedby
\underset{\text{(Perfectly normal)}}{T_6}
$$

Why doesn't anyone label another property as a "T"? I could add space properties like this:

$$
\underset{\text{(Kolmogorov)}}{T_0} \impliedby
\underset{\text{(Fréchet)}}{T_1} \impliedby
\underset{\text{(US)}}{T_{1¼}} \impliedby
\underset{\text{(Weakly Hausdorff)}}{T_{1½}} \impliedby
\underset{\text{(KC)}}{T_{1¾}} \impliedby
\underset{\text{(Hausdorff)}}{T_2} \impliedby
\underset{\text{(Urysohn)}}{T_{2½}} \impliedby
\underset{\text{(Regular)}}{T_3} \impliedby
\underset{\text{(Tychonoff)}}{T_{3½}} \impliedby
\underset{\text{(Normal)}}{T_4} \impliedby
\underset{\text{(Completely normal)}}{T_5} \impliedby
\underset{\text{(Perfectly normal)}}{T_6} \impliedby
\underset{\text{(Metrizable)}}{T_7} \impliedby
\underset{\text{(Completely metrizable)}}{T_8} \impliedby
\underset{\text{(Discrete)}}{T_\infty}
$$

Is this acceptable? In particular, why doesn't metrizability qualify as a separation axiom?

Comment: What do you mean with “US” (your $T_{1¼}$)? BTW, in trying to search for it, I've come across the following PDF that might interest you: [Separation Axioms Between $T_0$ and $T_1$](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82702431.pdf)

Comment: @celtschk Here. https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/US-space

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that site; bookmarked it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hierarchy is correct, but the question **why** nobody has introduced $T_x$-names for the additional properties cannot be reasonably answered. It is a question of mathematical tradition, and you cannot exclude someone will suggest to introduce another $T_x$-name, but it is uncertain whether this will be accepted in the mathematical community.

Metrizability has relations to separation axioms, but in my opinion it does not add a new quality in separating points and closed sets. Being completely metrizable definitely has no connection to separation.

Comment: At least discrete spaces being $T_\infty$ is completely reasonable, I think. It literally separates every point from another.

Comment: @DannyuNDos: On the other hand, there is exactly one topology per set that fulfils that condition, namely the discrete topology. I'm not sure if it makes sense to define a separation axiom for just one topology. Otherwise, why not also add $T_{-\infty} = \text{not indiscrete}$?

Comment: @celtschk $T_\infty$ must imply every other $T_x$. That prevents compact metrizability being $T_9$.

Comment: @celtschk Nontriviality as a seperation axiom seems kinda off, for the empty space and the one-point space are always trivial.